# Why Linq can't translate expression/treat as local expression and throws an exception?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264985/linq-could-not-translate-expression-into-sql-and-could-not-treat-it-as-a-loca) about an Linq error that results from mixing Linq-To-SQL with C# code.  In brief, the compiler gets confused and doesn't realize that you are intending to call a local function on the resultset **after** it's come back from the database.

The answer I accepted was to use `AsEnumerable()` on the result set, thus forcing it to return all columns before doing any further calculations.

My problem now is that in a very similar way, I am now trying to invoke a method of an object that is related to my resultset via a foreign key, e.g.:

```
var q =
  from c in MyCities.AsEnumerable() // note the AsEnumerable, forcing the query to execute before accessing properties of c
  let cy = c.County
  select new { CityName = c.Name, CountyName = cy.Name, CountyFoo = cy.Foo() };
```

And guess what - this throws that ol' exception again.  Why?  Clearly because we need to go back to the database again in order to load the related `County` of `c`.  Only this time, I can't call `AsEnumerable()`, because `c` has only one County, not a collection!

Dwat that wascawwy wabbit!

How do I get around this one?

Comment: What is the exception that you get?

Comment: @Pop: See the question referenced in my text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more level of indirection should fix it, though I don't know how readable this is. Remove `CountyFoo = cy.Foo()` and `CountyName = cy.Name` from your result set and replace it with `County = cy` to give you..

```
var q =
  from c in MyCities.AsEnumerable() 
  let cy = c.County
  select new { CityName = c.Name, County = cy };
```

then add

```
var p = q.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
    new 
    { 
        CityName = x.CityName, 
        CountyName = x.County.Name, 
        CountyFoo = x.County.Foo() 
    });
```

You can then enumerate over `p`. This is quite obfuscated, though. Why do you need all of this in line LINQ query?

Comment: Assuming you give p and q better names, I wouldn't consider this particularly obfuscated. First retrieve the data from SQL, then do some client-side processing on the result.

Comment: And you probably meant to remove the call to AsEnumerable() from q.

Comment: @dahlbk: Actually the AsEnumerable() is necessary to translate it to a LINQ to Objects query rather than a LINQ to SQL query.